# Exporting and Importing Printer Settings

Tags: drivers, printer, windows-registry, label-printer

Recently we have recently been upgrading label printers (Godex DT4) in our production areas and the printer settings for the label printer are not carrying over to new users who log into the domain. Here's an example.

I log into the Domain with my credentials and install a new label printer and load the printer drivers. I modify the settings so the printer will work properly with the labels we currently use and do a test print, which works fine. I log out of the computer and let Joe log in using his credentials. None of the settings I made are in the printer properties. I have to manually configure those settings for each individual user.

I have reached out to the manufacturer of the label printers (Godex) and have not received a response. I am using their most recent printer drivers downloaded directly from their website. Any documentation I find does not list any issues similar to the one that I am having.

At this point, my best guess is that we may need to export the registry settings on an already configured domain login and then find a way to import those same registry settings for each user that will need to use that computer to print labels.

I have tried to locate where the printer registry settings are located, but I have not had much luck. Since settings are not being saved on the computer, I assume that they would be under HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive. At this point I have tried to export a few registry files like HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Seagull Scientific\Drivers\Printers\Godex DT4\Settings and then import them when logged in to a different user, but this does not appear to do anything.

If anyone can give me some guidance I would appreciate it greatly. If there are any questions, feel free to let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command [**`printUI`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx) for this.

To export the the printer settings to a file the following command can be used:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss
```

Example:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Ss /n "printer" /a "outputfile.dat"
```

---

To import the printer settings from a file the following command can be used:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr
```

Example:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Sr /n "printer" /a "inputfile.dat"
```